# addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask not working on some computers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm using this code to capture Global Keyboard Shortcuts in my app.

This works great on almost every computer I run it on. I tried it on a brand new Retina Macbook Pro this week and `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask` doesn't work at all. It doesn't even log every key like I have it set up to do here for debugging.

Is there a more reliable way to do this? Right now I load this on `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

I think it might make more sense to load it as its own method in the App Delegate but I'm not sure what the syntax of that would look like.

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *event){

    NSLog(@"sequence = %li", (unsigned long)[event modifierFlags]);

    // Activate app when pressing cmd-c
    if([event modifierFlags] == 1048840 && [[event charactersIgnoringModifiers] compare:@"c"] == 0) {
```

Answer (score 8):

In OSX 10.9 (Mavericks) the setting has moved to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility - make sure your app is checked.

Comment: To make it clearer, you should say "make sure **Xcode** is checked."

Comment: Is there a way in code to detect if your app is checked? I'd like to alert users to change this setting rather than silently failing.

Comment: @sja26 Can we do this programmatically ?

Comment: Yes, you can check `AXIsProcessTrusted()`.

Answer (score 0):

check the "Enable access for assistive devies" in accessiblity in system prefrences and try again.