# Global key Accessibility in cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am working in Cocoa.

I have made changes to my application as per the answer recommended by [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002942/addglobalmonitorforeventsmatchingmask-not-working-on-some-computers)

I have following questions:

1. Can I add my app to System Accessibility List programmatically after taking users consent, so that it is seen checked in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility.(Like they do it in iOS where app requests user to show notifications, and user can choose between Dont allow and Ok).
2. After the application is successfully added to the Accessibility list how do I get the value of checkbox in Accessibilty list programatically ?

---

I am expecting a sandbox/"app store" compatible answer

Comment: Might get more traction with this question on one of the apple lists.

Answer (score 2):

You can have 1) done automatically by passing in `kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt` whilst querying 2) with `AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions`:

```
NSDictionary *prompt = @{kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt:@YES};
BOOL accessible = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions((CFDictionaryRef)prompt);
```

This will provide whatever the current system standard dialog is for the user consenting to trust your app.

Comment: Thanks. Will this work for sanboxed enabled environment ? Actually, I was looking for "App Store" compatible solution

Comment: That's specifically what this option is for, I believe; you're not allowed to call `AXMakeProcessTrusted` yourself in the sandbox, setting this option so that the System takes the user to the right place to trust it themselves is as close as you can get.

Comment: Still works at least on Mojave / macOS 10.14.6. My (ARC-based) project required me to cast the key to an NSString, though: `(__bridge NSString *)kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt:@YES`.